# Limit Columns Shown from GirdView.DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've got a `GridView` control that is using an `IList<>` for it's `DataSource`. The `List<>` holds objects of type:

```
class Foo {
    public string prop1 {get;set;}
    public int prop2 {get;set;}
    public int prop3 {get;set;}
    public float prop4 {get;set;}
}
```

Is there any way that when I bind the `List` to the `GridView` that I can specify, for example, that I only want to generate columns for `prop1 and prop2` ? Thanks for any help

Edit:

My overall goal for this is to have a checkbox on the form that will allow the user to toggle between seeing the full table and a shortened table only showing the most important columns. The real objects have over 50 properties and I'd like to only show the most important 10 if the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 2):

If you need both views (important columns / all columns) then set the visibility of the columns at the event handler of the checkbox:

```
gridView.Columns["Prop1"].Visible = showAllColumnsCheckBox.Checked;
gridView.Columns["Prop2"].Visible = showAllColumnsCheckBox.Checked;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works, but you could try:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Prop1"> 
     <ItemTemplate>  
        <%# ((Foo)Container.DataItem).prop1 %>  
     </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField> 

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Prop2"> 
     <ItemTemplate>  
        <%# ((Foo)Container.DataItem).prop2 %>  
     </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was hoping for something a little more dynamic . Check out my edit for a better explanation of what I'm trying to do.